# Rails has_many associations at both sides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have users. Every user can create journey. When user create journey, other users can join to jorney. How to create associations right?

In user_model:
`has_many :journeys` 
In journey_model:
`belong_to :user`
Can I add to journey_model: `has_many :users`?

Comment: Have a look at [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: @willem, thanks. But how to create migration?

Comment: Have a look at the [HABTM](http://puneetpandey.com/tag/rails-4-habtm-tutorial/) tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :created_journeys, class_name: "Journey", foreign_key: :user_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :journeys
end

#Need a table journeys_users - journey_id | user_id

#app/models/journey.rb
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@user = User.find params[:user_id]
@journey = @user.journeys.find params[:id]

@journey << current_user
```

---

**Many-to-Many**

The crux of your issue is that you're looking for a *many-to-many* association.

This comes in two flavours:

- [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
- [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Both of these work to deliver a similar result, just in different ways:

[image]

I can explain more if required.

Comment: what means :created_journeys in has_many? Is it attribute or column in table?

Comment: It's from your current association -- each `journey` belongs to `user`, therefore each `user` has_many `journeys`